# Running a series of python modules with imports

Tags: python, package

I've written a bunch of `.py` files, in the standard package structure, with scripts and `__init__.py` in each subdirectory. Many of these `.py` modules import from each other using 'absolute imports', such as

```
from  mypkg.utils.functions import transform
```

Each one has a `run` function and has

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I want to run a single command-line command that will a series of these modules. I'm currently using a shell script, of the form

```
cd /parent_of_mypkg/
python -m mypkg.build.run_first
python -m mypkg.build.run_second    
python -m mypkg.build.run_third
python -m mypkg.build.run_fourth
```

Currently, if there is an error in `run_second`, it'll just skip to `run_third`, but I'd like it to stop and alert me to the exception.

One approach, mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187496/3346095), is

```
import mypkg.build.run_first as run_first
import mypkg.build.run_second as run_second
import mypkg.build.run_third as run_third
import mypkg.build.run_fourth as run_fourth
run_first.main()
run_second.main()
run_third.main()
run_fourth.main()
```

but this seems a bit cumbersome and repetitive. Is there a nice way to do this in Python?

Comment: An easy solution is to add `set -e` to your shell script.

Comment: @Robᵩ Sorry, where?

Comment: On the line that Immediately precedes the `cd` command.